# Spring Boot ignores logout() configuration when also using requestMatchers()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In Spring Boot, I'm having issues declaring a custom SuccessLogoutHandler while also restricting the security configuration with `requestMatchers()`.

I'm implementing an OAuth 2.0 authorization and resource server with Spring Boot, and the security configuration looks like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers()
            .mvcMatchers("/login", "/profile")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")  // This makes sure our custom form is rendered instead of Spring's default
            .successHandler(this.authenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(this.authenticationFailureHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
        ;
}
```

As you can see, I'm limiting the configuration to /login and /profile with `requestMatchers()`. I cannot remove this and configure the security for all endpoints because the application also defines some OAuth 2.0 security aspects with `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and `@EnableResourceServer`.

What I'm trying to do is configure a custom `LogoutSucessHandler` with `logout().logoutSuccessHandler()`. However, the configuration above falls back to the default logout handler (the one that redirects to /login?logout).

For testing purposes, the success handler adds a message to the session which is displayed in the login page. However, after the user logs out such message does not appear and the system redirects to `login?logout`. On the other hand, if I remove `requestMatchers`, then the message is successfully added to the session and the system redirects to /login.

The handler looks like this:

```
private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
    return new LogoutSuccessHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("message", "You have been signed out");
            response.sendRedirect("/login");
        }

    };
}
```

Do you know how to configure `logout()` while also using `requestMatchers()`?
Should I put that `logout()` somewhere else?

Comment: can you add your `logoutSuccessHandler`?

Comment: Hi! I've added details about the success handler. Thanks.

Comment: so your issue is it gets redirected to `/login?logout` instead of `/login`?

Comment: That's basically the key to identify the success logout handler is not getting called, yes. My issue is that I would like to have any sort of custom behaviour when the user logs out, but I'm not being able to tell Spring that I want it to call my handler instead of the default.

Comment: Your issue is you are adding it to session and the session will be invalidated on logout. If you add a `System.out.println()` in your handler, it will get printed

Comment: Nothing is printed, not even using a Logger. If the code was being called then I should also get the variable in the session, but that's not the case either. Also, if I remove `requestMatchers()` the logout behaves as expected, the message is added to the session and displayed in the login page.

Comment: But the session will be invalidated on logout

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment above. The message in the session works fine when removing `requestMatchers()`. Anyway, that's not an issue, in the production system we won't necessarily need to touch the session. I'm trying to figure out how to setup a custom handler for future stuff.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in DelegatingLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess to see what logoutHandlers are present? It should have all the handlers. `this.matcherToHandler.entrySet()`

Comment: Can you replace `requestMatchers().mvcMatchers("/login", "/profile")` with requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/profile")`?  `MvcRequestMatcher` is doing the matching based on controller

Comment: Changing the type of matcher didn't help. I'll try the breakpoint option and come back with the output

Comment: Thanks for your help. Debugging this was taking too much of my working time so I had to drop it off. For the record, after several tries I've confirmed the thoughts that limiting the `http` configuration to `requestMatchers` inhibits the functioning of `logout`. It seems logic, though, because `logout` would be changing an overall rule from a restricted environment.